# How to check if SOUND is ON/OFF on HTML5 video

Tags: html5-video

I need to show Sound icon on top of the video, when sound is OFF and hide it when sound is ON. For some reason the code below is not working.

```
if (video.prop('muted') === true) {
      video.mouseenter( function() {sound.show()} ).mouseleave( function() {sound.hide()} );
    }
else {
   sound.hide();
 }

<video id="video" controls  muted preload="none" width="446" height="250"></video>
```

I figured it out. Now it works like that.

```
 video.mouseenter( function() {
  if (video.prop('muted') === true) {
    sound.show()
  }
  else {
    sound.hide()
  }
});
video.mouseleave( function() {
  sound.hide();
});
```

Comment: Maybe video is not a HTML5 video element, did you check what it contains?

Comment: I have updated the code, video is standard HTML5 video

Answer (score 1):

Considering your `video` element:

```
<video id="video" controls muted preload="none" width="446" height="250">
</video>
```

You can determine whether sound is on by testing the `volume` and `muted` media properties of the element:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");
if (video.muted || video.volume === 0) {
    // Sound is off
}
```